# Prove that a two periodic function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I've given the following assignment: Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continous function such that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R},  \ f(x+2)= f(x)$.(two periodic function) I have to prove that:

a) The function is bounded and has a minimum and maximum value

b)$\exists x_{0}  \ such  \ that  ,  \ f(x_{0}+ \pi)= f(x_{0})$

There is a function to which applies $h(x)= f(x+\pi)-f(x)$ but can you explain how to construct the formal proof?

Comment: Since your title focuses on part (a), isn't it best to start there?

Comment: Hint for (a): Consider the behaviour of $f$ for $x\in[0,2]$, and then generalise to all $x$.

Comment: Hint for (b): You want to use the result from (a), so evaluate $h$ at the minimum and maximum of $f$ and use continuity.

Answer (score 1):

**Part A**

Consider $D = f([0,2])$

As $f$ is c.t.s and $[0,2]$ is bounded we have that $D$ is a bounded interval. That is $\forall y \in D$ $B_1 \leq y \leq B_2$

However from the periodicity we know that $f(x) \in D $

Hence $B_1 \leq f(x) \leq B_2$

**Part B**

Let $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ respectively denote the points where $f$ attains its minimum and maximum bounds.

Then $h(x_{min}) = f(x_{min} + \pi) - f(x_{min} ) $ and $h(x_{max}) = f(x_{max} + \pi) - f(x_{max} ) $

However we know that $f(x_{max}) \geq f(x)$ $ \forall x$ so most certainly $f(x_{max}) \geq f(x_{max}+\pi)$

Hence $h(x_{max}) = f(x_{max} + \pi) - f(x_{max} ) \leq 0 $

Similarly for  $h(x_{min}) = f(x_{min} + \pi) - f(x_{min} ) \geq 0  $

If either of these inequalities are not strict, that is $h(x_{max})$ or $  h(x_{min}) = 0 $ then we are done as we have a root to $h(x)$ which implies the existence of a point such that $f(x+\pi) = f(x)$

So let us assume they are both strict. That is $h(x_{max}) < 0 < h(x_{min})$

Hence Intermediate Value Theorem states $\exists x_0 $ such that $h(x_0) = 0 $ and we are done